# How to upload the file in servlet with progerssbar

Tags: google-app-engine

In my project I want to update the *csv* file in *Google* app. At the same time I want to show the *progressbar* to the end user how can i do this. 
Please help me if you have total code.

I'am using *Serlvet, JSP and Google app* in my project.

index.jsp:

```html
    <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type='file'>.....
```

upload:

```java
    Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
    BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile"); 
    if (blobKey == null) {
        res.sendRedirect("/");
    } else {
        res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had sucess in the past with this:

[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

> File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bars and preview images for jQuery.
>   Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing.
>   Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.

As the data transfer mechanism is a standard POST you should also be able to intergrate this.

Comment: ya i red this tutorial but i can't understand when the user click the button i want to send the control to my own servlet but where i wirte this code i can't understand plase help me if u have coe